# Grails collections

Tags: grails, collections, groovy, grails-orm

I want to check if any of curently logged in user roles are in specific list of roles. But it can be any two collection.

Basically I want to check if any memeber of [x1,x3,x4] collection is contained in [x2,x3,x7]

How to do this in Groovy (Grails)?

Comment: What security plugin are you using in your application?  I ask because there may be a better way to achieve your goal, for example in spring-security-core use `SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted` (which should take account of the role hierarchy if you're using one, which a straight overlap check wouldn't).

Comment: @IanRoberts I'm using Spring Security and I can definitely use this.Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Collection#disjoint`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection%29) method:

```
def a = [5, 4, 3]
def b = [7, 6, 5]

// a contains a member of b if they are not disjoint.
assert !a.disjoint(b)
assert a.disjoint([8, 7, 6])
```

Other alternatives are `!a.intersect(b).empty` or `a.any { it in b }` but i think the `disjoint` solution is the most direct one and (wild speculation here) probably the most performant one as it doesn't need intermediate collections or closures (update: well, [the code for `disjoint`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L7828-7852) reveals that it does some some funky stuff under the hood... but then again nearly all Groovy methods do =P).

Answer (score 1):

Convert one of the list to a set and use the [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method to find the intersection.

```
def s1 = [x1,x3,x4] as Set
s1.retainAll([x2,x3,xy]).size() > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean check(Collection c1, Collection c2) {
    for(def i in c1) {
        if(c2.contains(i)) {
            return true
            break
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def a = [1,2,3] 
    def b = [3,4,5]
    def result = false 
    a.each{it->
         if(b.contains(it))
         result =true
    }
    return result
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: I am sorry for not adding any explanation. But i think the code is easy to understand.

Comment: I'm sure it is for both you and me... but just the other day i helped somebody on Stack Overflow who was in grade 5...  Such people are welcome on Stack Overflow - and we'd like to make sure they feel welcome and have lots of stuff to learn from. Can you please just add a single sentence of explanation to say: what you changed, and why the change makes the code work.